# How to delete duplicated rows based in a column value?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, delete-row

Given the following table

```
 123456.451 entered-auto_attendant
 123456.451 duration:76 real:76
 139651.526 entered-auto_attendant
 139651.526 duration:62 real:62`
 139382.537 entered-auto_attendant
```

Using a bash shell script based in Linux, I'd like to delete all the rows based on the value of column 1 (The one with the long number). Having into consideration that this number is a variable number

I've tried with

`awk '{a[$3]++}!(a[$3]-1)' file`

```
sort -u | uniq
```

But I am not getting the result which would be something like this, making a comparison between all the values of the first column, delete all the duplicates and show it

```
 123456.451 entered-auto_attendant
 139651.526 entered-auto_attendant
 139382.537 entered-auto_attendant
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you didn't give an expected output, does this work for you?

```
 awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

with your data, the output is:

```
123456.451 entered-auto_attendant
139651.526 entered-auto_attendant
139382.537 entered-auto_attendant
```

and this line prints only unique column1 line:

```
 awk '{a[$1]++;b[$1]=$0}END{for(x in a)if(a[x]==1)print b[x]}' file
```

output:

```
139382.537 entered-auto_attendant
```

Comment: +1: Minor typo - `b[$1]` should be `b[x]` in the `END` block.

Comment: And what if I need all the columns that start with 139382.537 (in this case)

Answer (score 7):

`uniq`, by default, compares the entire line. Since your lines are not identical, they are not removed.

You can use `sort` to conveniently sort by the first field and also delete duplicates of it:

```
sort -t ' ' -k 1,1 -u file
```

- `-t ' '` fields are separated by spaces
- `-k 1,1`: only look at the first field
- `-u`: delete duplicates

Additionally, you might have seen the `awk '!a[$0]++'` trick for deduplicating lines. You can make this dedupe on the first column only using `awk '!a[$1]++'`.

Comment: Upvoting this answer as I think its a bit more flexible. You could dedupe across multiple fields for example. Thats harder to do with awk.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' file
123456.451 duration:76 real:76
139651.526 duration:62 real:62
```

Comment: Good, but I'd like to have all the records that start with the same column, like in the description, in that case are 2 records with the same first column, but sometimes may be three or more

Comment: Isn't that what this answer is already doing. It is printing all the duplicate lines. What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

try this command

```
awk '!x[$1]++ { print $1, $2 }' file
```